# Tensorboard embedding visualization hanging when passed metadata (class labels)

Tags: python, tensorflow, visualization, tensorboard

Working with the new embedding visualisation capability in tensorboard (TF v1.0.1) I am having difficulty adding labels to the points it displays.  Basically when I try to add this metadata the embedding tool hangs and never loads.  Unfortunately the documentation for this tool is, at present, quite minimal.

I have a 250 class supervised classification being trained (on something like AlexNet) and I can visualise the final fc layer (fc8) fine during training using the embedding tool.

But as soon as I add some code to add labels to the plot i.e. to get the points in different colours by class (rather than all blue) the tab never loads (stuck on a message stating 'loading points' forever)

The code I add prior to the epoch/training loop is:

```
fw=open('snapshots/metadata.tsv','wt')
for i in range(0,250):
   fw.write('cat%d\n' % i)
fw.close()

tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, './', 'train.pbtxt')
config = projector.ProjectorConfig()
embedding = config.embeddings.add()
embedding.tensor_name = fc8.name
embedding.metadata_path = 'snapshots/metadata.tsv'
tmp_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(out_tb)
projector.visualize_embeddings(tmp_writer, config)
```

where fc8 is the tensor I want to visualise obtained earlier from the default graph.  All the checkpoints, tensorboard events and now the metadata (labels) itself are being written into a subfolder called 'snapshots'

The config file is being written out as projector_config.pbtxt as it should be, and contains

```
embeddings {
  tensor_name: "fc8/fc8:0"
  metadata_path: "snapshots/metadata.tsv"
}
```

If I delete this file then the embedding tab will load fine and won't hang i.e. I get to the dimmed screen and little white central box with 'loading tensors..' etc in it and an (unlabelled) point cloud is shown.

Am I misconfiguring this?  I don't get any errors logged to the console in which I invoke the tensorboard server even when I raise the GLOG level.

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved this - the tensor name in the file was incorrect, should have been:

```
 embeddings {
    tensor_name: "fc8/weights"
    metadata_path: "snapshots/metadata.tsv"
 }
```

It turns out if you put an invalid tensor_name in the config file then the tensorboard just hangs on loading the embedding tab / there is no error trapping (TF v1.0.1)

Comment: I can also agree with TF v1.1

Comment: Also on windows, watch the path names as I have found I need to use full absolute paths

Comment: Did you figure out why you were getting the wrong tensor_name in projector_config.pbtxt? Was it because the line embedding.tensor_name = fc8.name was wrong, or something else?